# Version Management - Business Objects add every object

Tags: svn, version-control, business-objects

HI I would like to add all of the objects in an environment to version management.  Like go to all universes and all folders.  I am just wondering the implications of this.  Should they be added separately? Where is everything stored, should I be checking in all objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer GIT for version management.
A project which consists of thousands of files can together come under a GIT repository.You can checkout the code from GIT repository and you can work off line on the checked out source code.
You can install GIT in any of your server machine and initialize a GIT repository there.You can checking in all your objects related to project to this repository.

Comment: BusinessObjects uses Subversion out of the box.  No one uses GIT with BOBJ